# vlm config file for streaming dvb-s2 input over http with vlc

Tags: vlc, dvb, dvblast

this my channels info getting from w_scan2

```
Qatar Today 1(EshailSat):10730:h:0:30000:931:932:10903
Almamlaka TV(Eshailsat):10730:h:0:30000:941:942:10904
Al Seraj TV(Eshailsat):10730:h:0:30000:951:952:10905
Al Jazeera(Al Jazeera):11604:h:0:27500:512:650:10501
```

i have tried so many different config file but there is no fully example for this work
my last try config file is this :

```
new dvb-s2 broadcast enabled

setup dvb-s2 input "dvb-s2://"
setup dvb-s2 option dvb-frequency=11230000000
setup dvb-s2 option polarization=H
setup dvb-s2 option srate=27500
setup dvb-s2 option inversion=2
setup dvb-s2 option modulation=8PSK
setup dvb-s2 option rolloff=0.35
setup dvb-s2 option pilot=off
setup dvb-s2 option tuner=0
setup dvb-s2 option programs=931,932


setup dvb-s2 output #duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:8080/qatar-today},select="program=931,932"}

control dvb-s2 play
```

but nothing play and this is some of errors :

```
main interface error: no suitable interface module
main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[Media: dvb-s2] dtv stream error: cannot set frontend tuning parameters: Invalid argument
[Media: dvb-s2] dtv stream error: tuning to 11230000000 Hz failed
[Media: dvb-s2] main stream error: Digital broadcasting
[Media: dvb-s2] main stream error: The selected digital tuner does not support the specified parameters.
Please check the preferences.
[Media: dvb-s2] main stream debug: no access modules matched
[Media: dvb-s2] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[Media: dvb-s2] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvb-s2://'. Check the log for details.
```